# Use mic input port as speaker output port ubuntu without hdajackretask

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones

I need to use my mic port as a speaker output port on my computer due to my speaker port being broken. hdajackretask does not work due an error `tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC1D0/reconfig: Device or resource busy` each time I attempt to configure mic as speaker output.

Comment: I came from windows and realtek audio console was able to solve this problem but the console is only for windows.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]